# Array is populated, but empty outside of brackets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

When I log my array self.userData inside of the below, the array is populated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        self.userData = [responseObject mutableCopy];

  NSLog(@"userData = %@", self.userData);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

However, the moment I try and take the populated data, and use it outside of these brackets (e.g. below), the array is empty? How can I fix this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        self.userData = [responseObject mutableCopy];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

    self.userBio.text = self.userData[0][@"userbio"];

    NSLog(@"userData = %@", self.userData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how async methods like AFHTTPRequestOperation work. The whole point is that such a method returns immediately, before the request has even been sent to the remote server.

Once the task is complete it calls your completion block. Any work you want to do once the data is available should be inside your completion block.

I don't remember if AFNetworking's completion methods are run on the main thread or on a background thread. Consult their docs. If the completion block is run from the background then you need to put UI changes in a call to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()).

### EDIT:

Taking a look at the docs, it looks like the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` class you're using defaults to invoking your completion block on the main queue unless you specify a different queue by setting the `successCallbackQueue` property.

Thus, unless you've set the `successCallbackQueue`, you don't need to worry about inclosing UI operations in a call to dispatch_async().

Comment: This makes sense - however when I execute this line inside of my completion block, it almost takes a few seconds longer to load? self.userBio.text = self.userData[0][@"userbio"];

Comment: Yes, it would. Networking calls have to go out on the network, send a request, and then wait for the response. There's no way you can speed that up. The point of using an async call with a completion block is that you don't freeze the UI while you're waiting.

Comment: Ahhh got it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The array is populated in both examples.

Since `AFHTTPRequestOperation` works asynchronously the block returns the data after `viewDidLoad` did finish and therefore after the `NSLog` line is executed in the second example.

Comment: It can't be populated in both examples, because when I try and use self.userData outside of the brackets it crashes my app, saying index 0 is beyond bounds. Which means my array is empty :/

Comment: It's populated in the success block which is called much later – in terms of computer speed – after `viewDidLoad` finished. At the time the `NSLog` line is `executed` the array is – still – empty and there is no first item.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you success operation block is dispatched asyncroniously. That is, it happens on another thread. So, when you try to access your userData after the brackets, your code inside success block didn't get chance to execute.
The easiest way is to use semaphore. But meaning of "fix" depends on your specific case - what data you receive and what for will you use it. You can call some method from within the brackets , you can post NSNotification. As I said, you should consider using the best way for your specific task

Comment: You're right; if I move the line self.userBio.text = self.userData[0][@"userbio"] inside of the brackets, it works :) That said, isn't there a way to just rewrite that line outside of the brackets, and call the data without NSNotification?

Comment: Two possible ways - move this line to some method, and call it from inside the block. Or use dispatch_semaphore to wait until completion of block. The second is dirty way

Answer (score 0):

In your AFNetworking success block add something like the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myDataSuccededLoading" object:nil];
```

Add in your viewDidLoad before the asynchronous call the notification observer as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleSuccess) name:@"myDataSuccededLoading" object:nil];
```

Add a void method to handle success (handleSuccess). Maybe you should consider to repeat the above (with different notification string) to handle failure...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
self.userBio.text = [self.userData[0]valueForkey@"userbio"];
```